# Access WPF control programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

The problem with this is probably obvious but im struggling to see it.

I have the following XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="contentList">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <ItemsControl x:Name="imageContent" Grid.Column="1">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageCollection.FullName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I've set up the itemsSource for contentList like so:

```
contentList.ItemsSource = myObservableCollection;
```

However when I try to do the same for imageContent, I can't seem to access it via IntelliSense.
I've tried a clean/rebuild of the Project and it's made no difference.

Do I need to access imageContent a different way?

I want to use myObservableCollection for both contentList and imageContent as it has the following structure:

- Name (String)
- ImageCollection (ObservableCollection)

With an aim to produce the following UI:

[image]

Comment: Your `imageContent` is inside the ItemTemplate of the outer control. When that outer control is bound to >= 2 items, how unique is `imageContent` then ?

Comment: I see, there would be multiple controls with the same name. Am I trying to use controls incorrectly?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to name it. But you should be able to bind it to a list of Items. Like the `{Binding Name}` in the previous control: `{Binding List}`

Comment: Ive tried setting the binding for the TextBlock to be {Binding Name} as a test and theres no additional output. The Output window does not seem to complain about incorrect bindings either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define another ObservableCollection within the list objects of your outer collection.  Something like this:

```
ObservableCollection<MyObject> OuterList = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();

//...


public class MyObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<FileInfo> ImageCollection {get; set;}
    public MyObject()
    {
        ImageCollection = new ObservableCollection<FileInfo>();
    }
}
```

Then just update your xaml like so:

```
...
<ItemsControl x:Name="imageContent" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageCollection}">
...
```

So this will cause each item in your outer list to hold it's own observable collection holding it's list.

Also with this change make sure you update the binding on your text block, since each item will represent a FileInfo object you can simply write this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks KDiTraglia, but the ItemsSource I would like to use is the myObservableCollection object which itself has a property called ImageCollection of type ObservableCollection<FileInfo> . This is why I have a binding of ImageCollection.FullName. I've updated my question with more information and would be grateful for any input.

Comment: @JamieKeeling Sounds like you just need this line in your xaml then, `ItemsSource="{Binding ImageCollection}"`.  Just make sure it is a property (has a getter and setter)

Comment: The life is nice and easy if your data structure reflects directly what you display. You need an outer collection each item of which represents one line. This item would have two properties: name, and list of FileInfo's. Thus, you will have multiple collections of FileInfo's: one per name.

A single giant collection of FileInfo is of little use for data binding, as it can only produce a single giant line of objects.

Comment: Thanks for the information @IvanKrivyakov, reworked my XAML based on your advice and it works great.